# Is it possible to write code with `function`, not using `class` in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

While I was writing code in ReactJS, I realized that I might be able to write code with function, not using class.

But it seems like it doesn't work and I'm actually a beginner at coding.

it keeps showing the error on Movie.js:8, which is "TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined".

(Basically, it's the transforming process from 'using class' to 'using function'.)

It might be better if I just show you guys the code that I wrote.

Here's what I wrote in App.js file using function:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Movie from './Movie';

const movies = [
  "Matrix",
  "Full Metal Jacket",
  "Oldboy",
  "Star Wars"
]

function App(){
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Movie title={movies[0]} />
        <Movie title={movies[1]} />
        <Movie title={movies[2]} />
        <Movie title={movies[3]} />
      </div>
    )
}

export default App;
```

Here's what I wrote in Movie.js file using function:

```
import React from 'react';
import './Movie.css';

function Movie(){
        return(
            <div className="Movie">
                <MoviePoster />
                <h1>{this.props.title}</h1>
            </div>
        )
}

function MoviePoster(){
        return(
            <div className="MoviePoster">
                <img src="http://ojsfile.ohmynews.com/down/images/1/1243342935.jpg" />
            </div>
        )
}

export default Movie;
```

And just for reference, here's how I wrote in App.js file using class:

```
import React, {Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Movie from './Movie';

const movies = [
  "Matrix",
  "Full Metal Jacket",
  "Oldboy",
  "Star Wars"
]

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Movie title={movies[0]} />
        <Movie title={movies[1]} />
        <Movie title={movies[2]} />
        <Movie title={movies[3]} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Just for reference, here's how I wrote in Movie.js file using class:

```
import React , { Component } from 'react';
import './Movie.css';

class Movie extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <MoviePoster />
                <h1>{this.props.title}</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class MoviePoster extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <img src="http://ojsfile.ohmynews.com/down/images/1/1243342935.jpg" />
        )
    }
}

export default Movie;
```

Long story short,

I'm trying to transform code from "Movie.js using class" to "Movie.js using function" AND "App.js using class" to "App.js using function".

Comment: In functional components, `props` is passed as an argument to the function, it's not `this.props`

Comment: have you looked at [Hooks?](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a React component using the `function` syntax, you need to write a function Starting an uppercase letter which takes a `props` input and returns an instance of a React Element.

So you need to get the `props` from from the parameter of the `function`:

```
import React from 'react';
import './Movie.css';

function Movie(props){
        return(
            <div className="Movie">
                <MoviePoster />
                <h1>{props.title}</h1>
            </div>
        );
}

function MoviePoster(props){
        return(
            <div className="MoviePoster">
                <img src="http://ojsfile.ohmynews.com/down/images/1/1243342935.jpg" />
            </div>
        );
}

export default Movie;
```

From the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html):

> The simplest way to define a component is to write a JavaScript
>   function:
>
> `function Welcome(props) {   return <h1>Hello, {props.name}</h1>; }`
>
> This function is a valid React component because it accepts a single
>   “props” (which stands for properties) object argument with data and
>   returns a React element. We call such components “function components”
>   because they are literally JavaScript functions.

Comment: Thank you so much, I appreciate that! I love you

Comment: @jpworld great! please accept my answer if you found it helpful!

Comment: Yes, I did! Thank you, sir. Is there anything else that should be done when got an answer? cos this is my first time getting an answer!

Comment: @jpworld Thank you! that will do for now!